# Was Second Variety brought up in connection with Ellison's suit against Cameron over Terminator?

Tags: the-terminator, philip-k-dick

It seems to me that if anyone had pointed out that some ideas in "Second Variety" were very similar to *Terminator*'s -- in particular, the "infiltrator" of *Terminator* is completely present in "Second Variety" -- it might have had significance in the Ellison legal action against James Cameron.

I am guessing no one was aware of "Second Variety" when Harlan sued James Cameron. Dick had passed away by the time of *Terminator* but he had kids who to this day continue to own and develop PKD's stories for film and TV.

I guess Ellison had the time travel thing but his characters were not even androids but instead humans who could actually be reasoned with -- *Second Variety* seems to me much closer to *Terminator*.

**EDIT: My question is, Was Second Variety brought up in connection with Ellison's suit against Cameron over Terminator?**

Comment: I *think* OP is asking if Dick's [Second Variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Variety) was also part of the suit against Cameron.  It seems unlikely; the lawsuit was more than just about the terminator itself (which is closer to the robot in Demon with a Glass Hand); if you look at the plot of the Outer Limits episode '[Soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldier_(The_Outer_Limits))', which Ellison was citing as the unacknowledged source, it had time travel, saving a present day woman from a future solider, etc.; a lot in common with Terminator.

Comment: @K-H-W: If you are applying for a patent and someone else was shown to have developed the same tech prior to you, patented or not, I believe u can't get the patent. So if it can be argued the Ellison also did not come up with the ideas of Terminator that he claimed because they were already in Dick's story, I believe Dick's estate could have sued but not Ellison. I never heard Ellison mention Second Variety. On the other hand, if you can sue over a time-traveling soldier alone, then Ellison deserved whatever he got. I support writers being paid for ideas.

Comment: Reasonable enough.. but neither Ellison nor Dick were first to have human looking robots; that's why his lawsuit seems to have been less about the Terminator concept, and more about the plot points. (Otherwise it would have been over Demon with the Glass Hand, not Soldier.)  Stealing from Wikipedia: **Some accounts of the settlement state that "Demon with a Glass Hand," another Outer Limits episode written by Ellison, was also claimed to have been plagiarized by the film, but Ellison explicitly stated that The Terminator "was a ripoff" of "Soldier" rather than of "Demon with a Glass Hand."**

Comment: And, I should mention, Soldier has two human soldiers, although one was bred for the job -- no Terminators, or robots, but it is what Ellison claimed was plagiarized (A Good soldier and a Evil soldier, back in time, being the base concept.) Again, supporting the idea that Second Variety wasn't related -- it was just another story with human simulacrums.  Ellison never actually sued, either, so you can't look at the trial docs -- it was settled out of court, against Cameron's wishes. https://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/0/sci-fis-true-terminator-story-harlan-ellisons-copyright-war/

Comment: @K-H-W: I'll never understand how intellectual property works. I believe it should be protected but it is double-edged -- you don't want to scare writers and inventors from developing ideas. And at least with inventions, improvements are allowed -- I assume same deal with fiction. As an aside, I think I read some pretty compelling stuff about Harry Potter being at least heavily inspired by an earlier work. Another aside: patent law is screwed up. Farnsworth made nothing from TV because of ww2. I think he shd have gotten an extension because of the years when TVs could not be mass manufactured.

Comment: Interestingly, "The Skull" by PKD is about a human sent back in time to assassinate an influential human to achieve victory in a future conflict.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: I guess PKD was a busy man (I mean, I know he was) -- he's been gone for 40 years and yet I keep reading of stories of his I don't recall. And I have been reading his since the 1960s. His greatest success after he's gone; I am sure he would be happy his kids are doing well from all the movies and TV shows.